# Use of "groin" as a verb

Tags: word-usage

I came across this line when reading Owen's *Strange Meeting*:

> It seemed that out of the battle I escaped
>
> Down some profound dull tunnel, long since scooped
>
> Through granites which Titanic wars had **groined**.

What does the last line really mean? Going by the dictionary, *groin* as a verb stands for 'to form the line of intersection of two vaults', but with this I am unable to bring **Titanic wars** into the picture.

Comment: The definition of [groin as a verb](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/groin) is available at Dictionary.com

Comment: I knew someone would say that. I am unable to correlate the dictionary definition with "Titanic wars".

Comment: If you do a little lookup first, it helps the answerers to know where to direct their advice.

Comment: @Mitch: Okay, I have edited the question slightly, please tell me if the title has to be changed too.

Comment: Hmm, the definition you quote makes sense to me in context. To "groin" is to join two hallways or tunnels or rooms that have arch-shaped ceilings. So in the quote, the writer has escaped into a cave where the intersecting tunnels were "groined", not by human construction workers, but by "Titanic wars". I'd guess he means "wars to the godlike Titans", probably as a metaphor for large-scale natural processes. Saying "I found a cave with tunnels that had been carved out and joined by large-scale natural processes" isn't quite as poetic.

Comment: Not exactly, Jay. This is an anti-war poem, so the assumption that wars stood for some 'processes' is not correct, I think.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [groined](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groin_vault) surface (Wikipedia link) would technically look like this:

[image]

Owen used the architectural term poetically to describe the inexorable power and awful grandeur of the war's effects on solid granite.

In one person's [analysis](http://voices.yahoo.com/analysis-wilfred-owens-strange-meeting-8915997.html):

> "Groined" is used here in place of the word grooved; the walls of the tunnel had been grooved by the titanic wars displacing the granite.

Answer (score 1):

Theres two meanings:

> n1) Old French groign (French groin), Burgundian groigno, Provençal
>   groing, grong, feminine groingna, Italian grugno, Old Portuguese gruin
>   < popular Latin *grunnium, < Latin grunnīre to grunt like a swine
>
> n2) originally grynde , grinde of uncertain origin; connection with
>   grain n.2 is excluded by the early form. The form grine appears in
>   1530, but did not finally displace grind until the last quarter of the
>   16th cent., when it underwent corruption into groin , probably through
>   phonetic association with groin n.1
>
> Prof. Skeat suggests that the original sense may have been a channel
>   or depression (compare 2), and that the word may be identical with Old
>   English grynde , recorded only in the sense of ‘abyss’, but
>   etymologically capable of meaning ‘depression’, ‘valley’ ( < prehist.
>   *grundjo- , < *grundu- ground n.; compare German grund , used dialect for ‘valley’; also grindle n.1, grindlet n.).

The grunting one seems more like what would happen in a battle.

Upvote for the other answer though!